# Windows Phone, dynamic style

Tags: wpf, silverlight, windows-phone-7, wpf-controls

I'm working on an app where I want the color of a few borders to change depending on the users choice of theme. The borders are partly placed in the xaml, but also dynamically generated throughout the app depending on choices the user make. I am also using a few LoopingSelector controls (from the Silverlight toolkit), that in turn also generate borders.

So, I was wondering how I should approach this problem. Initially I tried applying a style to the borders, and then changing the style depending on the choice of theme, but apparently styles are read-only during run time. I also figured I could iterate through and change the color of the borders, but it seems the LoopingSelector doesn't expose that property of its borders, or really, expose the controls at all.

So I assume I should use binding in some way, but as I'm still quite new to Silverlight I'm not really sure how to go about that.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a named resource, say **CustomBorderBrush**, that you are using in your XAML for the parts that are in the XAML, then you can access this brush from the Application's resources:

```
Border newBorder = new Border();
newBorder.BorderBrush = (Brush)Application.Current.Resources["CustomBorderBrush"];
```

If you additionally have a problem with the `LoopingSelector`, then that's a separate issue :) It sounds like you need to apply your own style to the `LoopingSelector` so that you can specify the brush value that you need.

Comment: Yes, but if I try to change this resource the compiler throws a Not implemented exception.

Comment: Ah I see what you're trying to do now. Are you tyring to provide a pre-determined set of themes or are you trying to let the user change parts of the theme themselves?

Comment: I have four pre-set themes that the user can choose from. Anyway, I managed to get it all working by defining four different DataTemplate's for each LoopingSelector, and set the ItemTemplate of them in code-behind depending on the theme chosen, while manually changing the color of everything else. And while functional, it does feel like quite an "ugly" solution, so if you know of another way, please let me know :)